# Show scrollbar only when scrolling and hide it when not scrolling

Tags: css

This works completely fine on desktops:

```
.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}
.container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: none;
}
.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #f5f5f573;
  border-radius: 50px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}

.container:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

The `container` is the container for the color buttons. The problem is that it doesn't disappear on mobile devices. Is there a way that I can make the scrollbar disappear **when not scrolling** down on *mobile devices*? And then just **reappear** when I scroll again?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this way will only hide the scrollbar for chrome and some other browsers but might not work with other browsers.
I would recommend looking at this StackOverflow question: [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
}
```